# Heapster not fetching data from nodes

Tags: kubernetes, heapster

I have deployed kubernetes 1.2.4 with heapster, grafana and influxdb on ubuntu cluster.

```
kubectl cluster-info

Kubernetes master is running at http://192.168.56.10:8080
Heapster is running at http://192.168.56.10:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster
KubeDNS is running at http://192.168.56.10:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns
kubernetes-dashboard is running at http://192.168.56.10:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard
Grafana is running at http://192.168.56.10:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-grafana
InfluxDB is running at http://192.168.56.10:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-influxdb
```

grafna and heapster RestAPI both are listing node level details. 
but when I am trying to get namespace level detail its not giving anything its giving empty value.

output of `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` is:

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                   READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default       hazelcast-dymfs                        1/1       Running   0          42m
kube-system   heapster-v1.0.2-1238126759-jof6m       4/4       Running   0          1h
kube-system   kube-dns-v11-simv4                     4/4       Running   0          1d
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-v1.0.1-abut5      1/1       Running   0          1d
kube-system   monitoring-influxdb-grafana-v3-38exi   2/2       Running   0          1h
```

Below are the heapster container log

```
["kubectl logs heapster-v1.0.2-1238126759-jof6m --namespace=kube-system heapster"]<br>
`I0619 18:23:05.048147       1 manager.go:152] ScrapeMetrics: time: 47.671952ms size: 9
I0619 18:24:05.000197       1 manager.go:79] Scraping metrics start: 2016-06-19 18:23:00 +0000 UTC, end: 2016-06-19 18:24:00 +0000 UTC
I0619 18:24:05.032203       1 manager.go:152] ScrapeMetrics: time: 31.662441ms size: 9
I0619 18:25:05.022755       1 manager.go:79] Scraping metrics start: 2016-06-19 18:24:00 +0000 UTC, end: 2016-06-19 18:25:00 +0000 UTC
I0619 18:25:05.047227       1 manager.go:152] ScrapeMetrics: time: 24.379296ms size: 9
I0619 18:26:05.000176       1 manager.go:79] Scraping metrics start: 2016-06-19 18:25:00 +0000 UTC, end: 2016-06-19 18:26:00 +0000 UTC
I0619 18:26:05.030686       1 manager.go:152] ScrapeMetrics: time: 30.431612ms size: 9
I0619 18:27:05.000275       1 manager.go:79] Scraping metrics start: 2016-06-19 18:26:00 +0000 UTC, end: 2016-06-19 18:27:00 +0000 UTC
I0619 18:27:05.024293       1 manager.go:152] ScrapeMetrics: time: 24.012249ms size: 9
I0619 18:28:05.000178       1 manager.go:79] Scraping metrics start: 2016-06-19 18:27:00 +0000 UTC, end: 2016-06-19 18:28:00 +0000 UTC
I0619 18:28:05.020069       1 manager.go:152] ScrapeMetrics: time: 19.813727ms size: 9
I0619 18:29:05.000163       1 manager.go:79] Scraping metrics start: 2016-06-19 18:28:00 +0000 UTC, end: 2016-06-19 18:29:00 +0000 UTC
I0619 18:29:05.019929       1 manager.go:152] ScrapeMetrics: time: 19.689754ms size: 9
I0619 18:30:05.000152       1 manager.go:79] Scraping metrics start: 2016-06-19 18:29:00 +0000 UTC, end: 2016-06-19 18:30:00 +0000 UTC
I0619 18:30:05.122992       1 manager.go:152] ScrapeMetrics: time: 122.775222ms size: 9
I0619 18:31:05.000177       1 manager.go:79] Scraping metrics start: 2016-06-19 18:30:00 +0000 UTC, end: 2016-06-19 18:31:00 +0000 UTC
I0619 18:31:05.032408       1 manager.go:152] ScrapeMetrics: time: 32.15377ms size: 9
I0619 18:32:05.000176       1 manager.go:79] Scraping metrics start: 2016-06-19 18:31:00 +0000 UTC, end: 2016-06-19 18:32:00 +0000 UTC
I0619 18:32:05.026673       1 manager.go:152] ScrapeMetrics: time: 26.424226ms size: 9
I0619 18:33:05.000128       1 manager.go:79] Scraping metrics start: 2016-06-19 18:32:00 +0000 UTC, end: 2016-06-19 18:33:00 +0000 UTC
I0619 18:33:05.021314       1 manager.go:152] ScrapeMetrics: time: 21.115352ms size: 9
I0619 18:34:05.000159       1 manager.go:79] Scraping metrics start: 2016-06-19 18:33:00 +0000 UTC, end: 2016-06-19 18:34:00 +0000 UTC
I0619 18:34:05.028069       1 manager.go:152] ScrapeMetrics: time: 27.845914ms size: 9
I0619 18:35:05.000150       1 manager.go:79] Scraping metrics start: 2016-06-19 18:34:00 +0000 UTC, end: 2016-06-19 18:35:00 +0000 UTC
I0619 18:35:05.044087       1 manager.go:152] ScrapeMetrics: time: 43.861766ms size: 9
I0619 18:36:05.000183       1 manager.go:79] Scraping metrics start: 2016-06-19 18:35:00 +0000 UTC, end: 2016-06-19 18:36:00 +0000 UTC
I0619 18:36:05.021248       1 manager.go:152] ScrapeMetrics: time: 20.998928ms size: 9
I0619 18:37:05.000153       1 manager.go:79] Scraping metrics start: 2016-06-19 18:36:00 +0000 UTC, end: 2016-06-19 18:37:00 +0000 UTC
I0619 18:37:05.014427       1 manager.go:152] ScrapeMetrics: time: 14.204355ms size: 9
I0619 18:38:05.000182       1 manager.go:79] Scraping metrics start: 2016-06-19 18:37:00 +0000 UTC, end: 2016-06-19 18:38:00 +0000 UTC
I0619 18:38:05.029795       1 manager.go:152] ScrapeMetrics: time: 29.537191ms size: 9
I0619 18:39:05.000176       1 manager.go:79] Scraping metrics start: 2016-06-19 18:38:00 +0000 UTC, end: 2016-06-19 18:39:00 +0000 UTC
I0619 18:39:05.027009       1 manager.go:152] ScrapeMetrics: time: 26.75411ms size: 9
I0619 18:40:05.000167       1 manager.go:79] Scraping metrics start: 2016-06-19 18:39:00 +0000 UTC, end: 2016-06-19 18:40:00 +0000 UTC
I0619 18:40:05.033115       1 manager.go:152] ScrapeMetrics: time: 32.876629ms size: 9
I0619 18:41:05.000167       1 manager.go:79] Scraping metrics start: 2016-06-19 18:40:00 +0000 UTC, end: 2016-06-19 18:41:00 +0000 UTC
I0619 18:41:05.017157       1 manager.go:152] ScrapeMetrics: time: 16.926043ms size: 9
I0619 18:42:05.000156       1 manager.go:79] Scraping metrics start: 2016-06-19 18:41:00 +0000 UTC, end: 2016-06-19 18:42:00 +0000 UTC
I0619 18:42:05.028695       1 manager.go:152] ScrapeMetrics: time: 28.287187ms size: 9
```

I don't no where to look for to get more log and find out the error.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Edit-1

I have posted the output of "kubectl get pods --all-namespaces" above but when I checked on Kubedash, heapster is not listed there.

Comment: what does `namespace level detail` mean to you?

Comment: you are trying to debug kubedash? or logging?

Comment: @MrE when I am calling heapster end point for namspace list or list of pods in a given namespace its giving empty ([]) result.
Also when I am running heapster-controller.yaml of "kubernetes 1.2.4" its not being listed on kube-dash. But its running and being listed in `kubectl get pods --namspace=kube-system`

Comment: what call are you making to heapster? after `kubectl exec -it <heapster-pod> /bin/sh` if I do `curl http://localhost:8082/api/v1/model/namespaces/` it gets me the namespaces. If that works, then you may have a problem with your service.

Comment: sawan@sawan:~$ kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-systemNAME                                   READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
heapster-v1.0.2-1238126759-3ozrv       4/4       Running   0          2d
kube-dns-v11-simv4                     4/4       Running   0          4d
kubernetes-dashboard-v1.0.1-abut5      1/1       Running   0          4d
monitoring-influxdb-grafana-v3-um612   2/2       Running   0          2d

sawan@sawan:~$ kubectl exec -it --namespace=kube-system heapster-v1.0.2-1238126759-3ozrv /bin/sh

/ # curl http://localhost:8082/api/v1/model/namespaces/

[]/ #

Comment: can you post your rc.yaml ?

Comment: I use: `image: gcr.io/google_containers/heapster:v1.0.2`

Comment: `command:
            - /heapster
            - --source=kubernetes
            - --sink=influxdb:http://monitoring-influxdb:8086
            - --metric_resolution=30s`

Comment: you also need to mount the certificates for SSL to the k8s api.